# Recent Payments List Problems

Tags: flutter, dart

I have ListView in my app and it shows us last payments. I am using like this in my body
myTransactions array includes last payments.

But when I open the recentpayments page, everytime this function working It adds the same array on top of the existing array and shows it.

T1
T2
T3
and when the T4 process comming and than after open the recent page I see:
**T1
T2
T3**
T1
T2
T3
T4
How can I solve this problem?

```
 ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TransactionCard(transaction: myTransactions[index]);
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(height: 10);
          },
          itemCount:
              (myTransactions.length > 5) ? 5 : myTransactions.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
```

And this is transaction card ui:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_payment/constants/app_textstyle.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_payment/data/transaction_data.dart';

class TransactionCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final TransactionModel transaction;
  const TransactionCard({Key? key, required this.transaction})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TransactionCard> createState() => _TransactionCardState();
}

class _TransactionCardState extends State<TransactionCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      //height: 30, cause of bug
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        border: Border.all(color: (Colors.grey[300])!),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  color: Color(0xFFFEC9EF),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(widget.transaction.avatar),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(widget.transaction.name,
                      style: ApptextStyle.LISTTILE_TITLE),
                  Text(
                    widget.transaction.month,
                    style: ApptextStyle.LISTTILE_SUB_TITLE,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(widget.transaction.currentBalance,
                      style: ApptextStyle.LISTTILE_TITLE),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      widget.transaction.changePercentageIndicator == "up"
                          ? Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.turnUp,
                              size: 10, color: Colors.green)
                          : Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.turnDown,
                              size: 10, color: Colors.red),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.transaction.changePercentage,
                        style: ApptextStyle.LISTTILE_SUB_TITLE,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I add the recent payments in myTransactions, I call the createNewTransactionModel function:

This is TransactionModel:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TransactionModel {
  String name;
  String avatar;
  String currentBalance;
  String month;
  String changePercentageIndicator;
  String changePercentage;
  Color color;

  TransactionModel({
    required this.avatar,
    required this.changePercentage,
    required this.changePercentageIndicator,
    required this.currentBalance,
    required this.month,
    required this.name,
    required this.color,
  });
}

List<TransactionModel> myTransactions = [];

void addLastPaymentsTransactionModel(String currentBalance, String changedValue,
    String changeState, String changeDate, String productName) {
  createNewTransactionModel(
      currentBalance, changedValue, changeState, changeDate, productName);
}

void createNewTransactionModel(String currentBalance, String changedValue,
    String changeState, String changeDate, String productName) {
  String date = (changeDate.split("T"))[0].trim();
  myTransactions.add(TransactionModel(
    avatar: "assets/icons/avatar1.png",
    currentBalance: currentBalance,
    changePercentage: changedValue,
    changePercentageIndicator: changeState,
    month: date,
    name: productName,
    color: (Colors.deepPurple[100])!,
  ));
}
```

Comment: When you get data plz create empty list in function scope and all data save in list.
Then local scope list set to global scope list.
It will works

Comment: Please show the code that assigns `myTransactions`.

Comment: @nvoigt I add please check When I add the recent payments in myTransactions, I call the createNewTransactionModel

Answer (score 0):

You always `.add` to your `myTransactions` list. You never clear it. It's no surprise that every time you get transactions, your list grows and grows and grows.

You have to reset it back to empty before you get the transactions and add them.

Comment: You are right but when I try this, if I add clear function before  when I add to data in array. Old values deleted because this array cleaning. User doing payment than after the back, I see successfuly last one payment. But when I go to add new payments older one deleted. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Don't you have a backend where you can query which the most recent payments are? I don't know how your program is structured. Why do you add to this list at all from the frontend?

Comment: yes I have backend with nodejs, and backed keeps payments. I get payments from nodejs with list in Flutter. TransactionCard frontend side. When user logged in I get old payments records and add to myTransactions List. But if I clean this, I lost old ones.

Comment: So you get them again from the backend? Why are you even adding to it in the frontend? Your recent payments should always just be "what the backend gives me", otherwise you have concurrency problems if other devices have the same app running.

Comment: Yes this is good point but my problem is I think in  ListView.separated() block because if I never add anything on myTransactions array when open recent page this myTransactions array size increament I didnt add anything.